# Optimizing a C++ Program for Data Processing Using Parallel Computing with OpenMP

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, openmp

I'm new to programming and trying to learn the concept of multiprocessing. To try some things out I've created a C++ program that processes and analyzes data. The program reads data from a JSON file, calculates a new value for the data class, applies a filter based on those values, and then sorts and outputs the data. I've employed OpenMP for parallel processing to optimize performance.

However, I feel there might be further optimizations possible, either in the way I'm handling data, sorting it, or in the parallel processing approach. I am looking for suggestions to make this code more efficient.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include "json.hpp"
#include "sha1.hpp"
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;
const int DataSize = 23;

class EcologyData
{
    double ecologyScore;

public:
    EcologyData()
    {
        this->ecologyScore = 0;
    }
    EcologyData(double value)
    {
        this->ecologyScore = value;
    }
    double getEcologyScore() const
    {
        return this->ecologyScore;
    }
    void setEcologyScore(double value)
    {
        this->ecologyScore = value;
    }
};

struct Car {
    string make;
    int year;
    double mpg;
    string hashCode;
    EcologyData ecologyScore;
};

double calculateEcologyScore(const Car& car) {
    return car.year * car.mpg;
}

bool meetsFilterCriteria(Car& car, double filterThreshold) {
    return car.ecologyScore.getEcologyScore() > filterThreshold;
}

class ResultMonitor
{
    array<Car, DataSize> cars;
    int currentSize = 0;

public:
    array<Car, DataSize> getCars()
    {
        return cars;
    }


    void addSorted(Car newCar)
    {
#pragma omp critical
        {
            if (currentSize == 0)
            {
                cars[currentSize] = newCar;
                currentSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                cars[currentSize] = newCar;
                currentSize++;

                for (int i = 0; i < currentSize - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < currentSize - i - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (cars[j].ecologyScore.getEcologyScore() > cars[j + 1].ecologyScore.getEcologyScore())
                        {
                            Car temp = cars[j];
                            cars[j] = cars[j + 1];
                            cars[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int getCount()
    {
        return currentSize;
    }
};

ResultMonitor resultMonitor;
array<Car, DataSize> cars;

double processCarData(Car& car, int threadId)
{
    SHA1 sha1;
    sha1.update(car.make);
    sha1.update(std::to_string(car.year));
    sha1.update(std::to_string(car.mpg));
    car.hashCode = sha1.final();

    car.ecologyScore = calculateEcologyScore(car);

    int filterCriteriaValue = 50000;

    if (meetsFilterCriteria(car, filterCriteriaValue))
    {
        resultMonitor.addSorted(car);
        return car.year + car.mpg;
    }
    return 0;
}

class OutputPrinter
{
private:
    static void printDashToConsole(int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            cout << "-";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    static void printDash(ofstream& output, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            output << "-";
        }
        output << endl;
    }
public:
    static void printInitialDataConsole(const array<Car, DataSize>& cars)
    {
        int dashCount = 51;

        cout << "Duomenu failo duomenys:" << endl;
        printDashToConsole(dashCount);

        cout << left << setw(23) << "| Make" << left << setw(12) << "| Year " << left << setw(15) << "| Ecology " << "|" << endl;
        printDashToConsole(dashCount);

        for (const auto& car : cars)
        {
            cout << "| " << left << setw(20) << car.make
                << " | " << left << setw(9) << car.year << " | "
                << left << setw(12) << car.mpg << " | " << endl;
        }

        printDashToConsole(dashCount);
    }

    static void printResults(const array<Car, DataSize>& sortedCars, int count, string outputFile)
    {
        ofstream output(outputFile, ios_base::app);
        int dashCount = 136;
        output << "Rezultatai" << endl;
        printDash(output, dashCount);
        output << left << setw(23) << "| Make" << left << setw(23) << "| Year " << left << setw(22) << "| Ecology " 
            << left << setw(23) << " | Ecology score" << left << setw(44) << " | HashCode" << "|" << endl;
        printDash(output, dashCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            output << "| " << left << setw(20) << sortedCars[i].make
                << " | " << left << setw(20) << sortedCars[i].year << " | "
                << left << setw(20) << sortedCars[i].mpg << " | "
                << left << setw(20) << sortedCars[i].ecologyScore.getEcologyScore() << " | "
                << left << setw(40) << sortedCars[i].hashCode << " |" << endl;
        }

        printDash(output, dashCount);
        output.close();
    }

    static void printInitialData(const array<Car, DataSize>& cars, string outputFile)
    {
        ofstream output(outputFile);
        int dashCount = 51;

        output << "Duomenu failo duomenys:" << endl;
        printDash(output, dashCount);

        output << left << setw(23) << "| Make" << left << setw(12) << "| Year " << left << setw(15) << "| Ecology " << "|" << endl;
        printDash(output, dashCount);

        for (const auto& car : cars)
        {
            output << "| " << left << setw(20) << car.make
                << " | " << left << setw(9) << car.year << " | "
                << left << setw(12) << car.mpg << " | " << endl;
        }
        printDash(output, dashCount);

        output << endl;
        output.close();
    }
};

int main()
{;
    ifstream inputFile("data.json");
    json jsonCars;
    inputFile >> jsonCars;

    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& carData : jsonCars)
    {
        if (i < DataSize) {
            Car car;
            car.make = carData["make"];
            car.year = carData["year"];
            car.mpg = carData["mpg"];
            cars[i++] = car;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    OutputPrinter::printInitialDataConsole(cars);
    OutputPrinter::printInitialData(cars, "results.txt");

    int size = cars.size();
    int threadCount = size / 4;

    auto ValuesForSum = new double[DataSize];
    int ValuesForSumIndex = 0;
    double sum = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threadCount) reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        auto totalThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int threadNumber = omp_get_thread_num();
        int chunkSize = size / 4;
        int leftower_chunks = size % 4;
        int start = threadNumber * chunkSize;
        int end;
        if (threadNumber == totalThreads - 1) {
            end = size;
        }
        else {
            end = start + chunkSize;
        }
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
        {
            Car car = cars[j];
            ValuesForSum[ValuesForSumIndex++] = processCarData(car, threadNumber);
            sum = accumulate(ValuesForSum + start, ValuesForSum + end, 0,
                [](double acc, double curr) { return acc + curr; });        }
    }
    cout << "Float ir int suma: " << sum << endl;

    array<Car, DataSize> sortedCars;
    sortedCars = resultMonitor.getCars();

    OutputPrinter::printResults(sortedCars, resultMonitor.getCount(), "rezultatai.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of time one should not specify the number of threads, and rather let OpenMP use the default value (which is generally the number of cores).

Comment: Side note: if you're new to C++, make sure you have a good handle on the fundamentals before ramping up the frustration with multi-threaded code.

Comment: Before trying to optimize the code, have you checked that it gives correct results, and also that the parallel version gives the same results that the sequential version?

Comment: Unrelated: calculateEcologyScore and meetsFilterCriteria can be made members of Car.

Comment: Also, please put only code that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Same as [this very similar question regarding CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77875835/10107454) (same class/exercise/teaching materials, I guess), this would be a better fit for the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), at least after making sure that the results are correct.

Comment: The code should indeed not work in parallel : there are data race in it. For example, `ValuesForSumIndex++` is UB since `ValuesForSumIndex` is not atomic and shared. Moreover, you use an OpenMP reduction but `sum = ...` so it is not actually a reduction and the final result is dependant of the execution order (data race which is also UB). You mutate global variables like `resultMonitor` in a parallel section without lock (yet another data race). I would be actually surprised if this program does not even crash.